# Searching by State in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to search for all places in a state, I thought the url below might work but sadly not, is it even possible?
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=kansas,usa&sensor=false&key=[insert key here]

Comment: Did you try it with a real key? Did you get any error?

Comment: You can't return _all_ places in a state. The places API [textsearch](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#TextSearchRequests) returns a maximum of 60 results in groups of 20.  The places API [radarsearch](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#RadarSearchRequests) will return a maximum of 200 results (but without all the details).

Comment: Yes I have tried it with a real key!, it needs to use the text search as this is the only api that provides the ability to search by name, the radar and nearby searches require a long/lat

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/nB2ej/

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addresscity }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    document.getElementById("lat").value=   latitude;
                   document.getElementById("lon").value=   longitude; 
                 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    var mapOptions = {
                 center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                  zoom: 8,
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

             };
});
```